# Why should I close all file descriptors after calling fork() and prior to calling exec...()? And how would I do it?

Tags: c, fork, exec, posix, file-descriptor

I've seen a lot of C code that tries to close all file descriptors between calling `fork()` and calling `exec...()`. Why is this commonly done and what is the best way to do it in my own code, as I've seen so many different implementations already?

Answer (score 34):

When calling `fork()`, your operation system creates a new process by simply cloning your existing process. The new process will be pretty much identical to the process it was cloned from, except for its process ID and any properties that are documented to be replaced or reset by the `fork()` call.

When calling any form of `exec...()`, the process image of the calling process is replaced by a new process image but other than that the process state is preserved. One consequence is that open file descriptors in the process file descriptor table prior to calling `exec...()` are still present in that table after calling it, so the new process code inherits access to them. I guess this has probably been done so that `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` are automatically inherited by child processes.

However, keep in mind that in POSIX C file descriptors are not only used to access actual files, they are also used for all kind of system and network sockets, pipes, shared memory identifiers, and so on. If you don't close these prior to calling `exec...()`, your new child process will get access to all of them, even to those resources it could not gain access on its own as it doesn't even have the required access rights. Think about a root process creating a non-root child process, yet this child would have access to all open file descriptors of the root parent process, including open files that should only be writable by root or protected server sockets below port 1024.

So unless you want a child process to inherit access to currently open file descriptors, as may explicitly be desired e.g. to capture `STDOUT` of a process or feed data via `STDIN` to that process, you are required to close them prior to calling `exec...()`. Not only because of security (which sometimes may play no role at all) but also because otherwise the child process will have less free file descriptors available (and think of a long chain of processes, each opening files and then spawning a sub-process... there will be less and less free file descriptors available).

One way to do that is to always open files using the flag `O_CLOEXEC`, which ensures that this file descriptor is automatically closed when `exec...()` is ever called. One problem with that solution is that you cannot control how external libraries may open files, so you cannot rely that all code will always set this flag.

Another problem is that this solution only works for file descriptors created with `open()`. You cannot pass that flag when creating sockets, pipes, etc. This is a known problem and some systems are working around that by offering the non-standard `acccept4()`, `pipe2()`, `dup3()`, and the `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag for sockets, however these are not yet POSIX standard and it's unknown if they will become standard (this is planned but until a new standard has been released we cannot know for sure, also it will take years until all systems have adopted them).

What you can do is to later on set the flag `FD_CLOEXEC` using `fcntl()` on the file descriptor, however, note that this isn't safe in a multi-thread environment. Just consider the following code:

```
int so = socket(...);
fcntl(so, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

If another thread calls `fork()` in between the first and the second line, which is of course possible, the flag has not yet been set yet and thus this file descriptor won't get closed.

So the only way that is really safe is to explicitly close them and this is not as easy as it may seem!

I've seen a lot of code that does stupid things like this:

```
for (int i = STDERR_FILENO + 1; i < 256; i++) close(i);
```

But just because some POSIX systems have a default limit of `256` doesn't mean that this limit cannot be raised. Also on some system the default limit is always higher to begin with.

Using `FD_SETSIZE` instead of `256` is equally wrong as just because the `select()` API has a hard limit by default on most systems doesn't mean that a process cannot have more open file descriptors than this limit (after all you don't have to use `select()` with them, you can use `poll()` API as a replacement and `poll()` has no upper limit on file descriptor numbers).

Always correct is to use `OPEN_MAX` instead of `256` as that is really the absolute maximum of file descriptors a process can have. The downside is that `OPEN_MAX` can theoretically be huge and doesn't reflect the real current runtime limit of a process.

To avoid having to close too many non-existing file descriptors, you can use this code instead:

```
int fdlimit = (int)sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
for (int i = STDERR_FILENO + 1; i < fdlimit; i++) close(i);
```

`sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)` is documented to update correctly if the open file limit (`RLIMIT_NOFILE`) has been raised using `setrlimit()`. The resource limits (`rlimits`) are the effective limits for a running process and for files they will always have to be between `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` (documented as the minimum number of file descriptors a process is always allowed to open, must be at least `20`) and `OPEN_MAX` (must be at least `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` and sets the upper limit).

While closing all possible descriptors in a loop is technically correct and will work as desired, it may try to close several thousand file descriptors, most of them will often not exist. Even if the `close()` call for a non-existing file descriptor is fast (which is not guaranteed by any standard), it may take a while on weaker systems (think of embedded devices, think of small single-board computers), which may be a problem.

So several systems have developed more efficient ways to solve this issue. Famous examples are [`closefrom()` and `fdwalk()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5168/6mbb3hr56/index.html) which BSD and Solaris systems support. Unfortunately The Open Group voted against adding `closefrom()` to the standard (quote): "*it is not possible to standardize an interface that closes arbitrary file descriptors above a certain value while still guaranteeing a conforming environment.*" ([Source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html)) This is of course nonsense, as they make the rules themselves and if they define that certain file descriptors can always be silently omitted from closing if the environment or system requires or the code itself requests that, then this would break no existing implementation of that function and still offer the desired functionality for the rest of us. Without these functions people will use a loop and do exactly what The Open Group tries to avoid here, so not adding it only makes the situation even worse.

On some platforms you are basically out of luck, e.g. macOS, which is fully POSIX conform. If you don't want to close all file descriptors in a loop on macOS, your only option is to not use `fork()`/`exec...()` but instead `posix_spawn()`. `posix_spawn()` is a newer API for platforms that don't support process forking, it can be implemented purely in user space on top of `fork()`/`exec...()` for those platforms that do support forking and can otherwise use some other API a platform offers for starting child processes.   On macOS there exists a non-standard flag `POSIX_SPAWN_CLOEXEC_DEFAULT`, which will tread all file descriptors as if the `CLOEXEC` flag has been set on them, except for those for that you explicitly specified file actions.

On Linux you can get a list of file descriptors by looking at the path `/proc/{PID}/fd/` with `{PID}` being the process ID of your process (`getpid()`), that is, if the proc file system has been mounted at all and it has been mounted to `/proc` (but a lot of Linux tools rely on that, not doing so would break many other things as well). Basically you can limit yourself to close all descriptors listed under this path.

Comment: what if another thread opens a file during your cycle?

Comment: @Nikita The order is: fork, close FDs in child, exec. Once you call fork, the current process is duplicated atomically and the calling thread becomes the new main thread of the child process. All other threads are dead in the child and never receive runtime (they freeze the moment you call fork), so they cannot open file descriptors while you are closing them in the child. Threads in the parent still can but those are no longer duplicated to the forked child. See https://0cn.de/xh1t and https://0cn.de/pp30 ("A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded...")

Comment: if we close all the files before exec., will the standard file descriptors 0,1,2 be recreated for the new process that is exec'd?

Comment: @mk.. No, they won't. If you close stdout, the newly created process has no stdout. Any attempt to write to stdout results in a failure (result of `printf()` will be negative and `errno` will be set). If you close stdin, any attempt to read from it results in a failure. The parent process must provide the child process with these streams, either by inheriting its own streams or by creating new ones (e.g. you can open a file and then make this file handle stdout, now all `printf()` calls will write to that file; or you can make one end of a pipe stdout of capture the output of the child).

Comment: @mk.. Note that if a child process has no stdin/out/err and opens up a file, the first file gets the descriptor id 0, the next one 1, etc. So these files  will then become stdin/out/err. This is dangerous security wise and can also lead to horrible malfunctions as code usually won't check for that. Because of that, it's good practice to open `/dev/null` and use that file id for stdin/out/err if you don't want a child process to have any of these. Writing to `/dev/null` just goes nowhere and is always safe, reading from it just returns "end of stream" (EOF).

Comment: Thanks Mecki. I took a look at supervisor/systemd implementation and they are precisely doing it the way you mentioned. Thank you very much for clearly explaining.

Answer (score 13):

True story: Once upon a time I wrote a simple little C program that opened a file, and I noticed that the file descriptor returned by `open` was 4.  "That's funny," I thought.  "Standard input, output, and error are always file descriptors 0, 1, and 2, so the first file descriptor you open is usually 3."

So I wrote another little C program that started reading from file descriptor 3 (without opening it, that is, but rather, assuming that 3 was a pre-opened fd, just like 0, 1, and 2).  It quickly became apparent that, on the Unix system I was using, *file descriptor 3 was pre-opened on the system password file*.  This was evidently a bug in the login program, which was exec'ing my login shell with fd 3 still open on the password file, and the stray fd was in turn being inherited by programs I ran from my shell.

Naturally the next thing I tried was a simple little C program to *write* to the pre-opened file descriptor 3, to see if I could modify the password file and give myself root access.  This, however, didn't work; the stray fd 3 was opened on the password file in read-only mode.

But at any rate, this helps to explain why you shouldn't leave file descriptors open when you exec a child process.

[Footnote: I said "true story", and it mostly is, but for the sake of the narrative I did change one detail.  In fact, the buggy version of /bin/login was leaving fd 3 opened on the groups file, `/etc/group`, not the password file.]

Comment: Well, it was readonly, but a writable group file handler would already be dangerous enough. It would allow you to add users to groups and all of a sudden I am member of the `sudo` group and can get a root shell.